# Characterize integral extension of rings by maximal ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\varphi:A\longrightarrow B$ be an integral extension of rings. Let $\varphi^*:\mathrm{Spec}(B)\to\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ denote the associate map. 
We know that $\varphi^*$ sends any closed point (maximal ideal of $B$) to a closed point and the preimage of any closed point of $A$ is closed.

(It is a not hard exercise in Qing Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves* (Chapter 2, exercise 1.8).)

I wonder that can these conditions characterize the integral extension?
That is, do the following proposition holds?

> Let $\varphi:A\longrightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism. If $\varphi^*$ maps a closed point to a close point, and that any preimage of a closed point is a closed point then $\varphi$ is integral.

I can't prove it and don't find examples, since the common non-integral extension in my mind such as
$\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[T]$ are not counterexamples.

Comment: Copying your proof might be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need any further knowledge in commutative algebra to come up with the easiest counterexample $k \to k[x]$.

If you want that any point, that is mapped to a closed point, is closed itself (Your comment suggests that), you must make sure the dimension does not drop, i.e. take $\mathbb C[x] \hookrightarrow \mathbb C[x,\frac{1}{x}]$. One spectra, this is an open immersion $\mathbb A^1 \setminus \{0\} \hookrightarrow \mathbb A^1$. Clearly any closed point is mapped to a closed point and the pre-image of any closed point is just the same closed point.

Comment: I realize this is not a counterexample. Since $0$ is not closed in $Spec(k[x])$, but it is a  preimage of the closed point of Spec(k).

Comment: @J.Li see my edit.